# How to redirect a jsf page from button

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, redirect, oracle-adf

Hi i'm trying to develop a login page using oracle **jdeveloper 12c** and. I'm working with **Java EE** technology and **JSF** pages.
I want to redirect  a page from a login button after verifying if user exist in the database If user was found it's redirect to MainPage.Jsf else redirect to Login.jsf The problem in both cases it redirect to Login.jsf .
PS: i didn't make any changes in the faces-config or the adfc-config this is my authentification function

```
    public String authentification(String login, String pwd) {

    try{
        Query query;
        query = em.createQuery("select o from UserEntity o where " + " o.login = :LOGIN AND o.pwd = :PWD");

        query.setParameter("LOGIN",login);
        query.setParameter("PWD",pwd);


              query.getSingleResult();


        return  ("success") ;  


    }
    catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
    }

}
```

i'm sure that the authenification function works correctly

this is my Dologin() in the managedBean

```
    public String DoLogin() {
    BindingContainer bindings = getBindings();
    OperationBinding operationBinding = bindings.getOperationBinding("authentification");
    Object result = operationBinding.execute();
    System.out.println("## Result = " + result);
    if (!operationBinding.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
        return "/faces/MainPage.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    return "/faces/Login.jsf?faces-redirect=true";

}
```

the log doesn't show me any exeption or error

Comment: Do you set servlet-mapping parameter in web.xml?(if your answer yes,how do it)

Comment: No i didn't do that :/

Comment: It is clear that the check !operationBinding.getErrors().isEmpty() returns false (which means no errors). Also, you are handling all exceptions generated from the authentication method, and if you don't see anything in the logs, it means no exception is thrown. The authentication method implementation doesn't seem correct.

Comment: No i'm sure that the authetification function works correctly in the logs when i write a invalide login and password it show me:
javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.
## Result = null
@Endrik

Answer (score 0):

**try this Code**

```
ExternalContext ectx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)ectx.getResponse();

response.sendRedirect("../faces/login.jspx");
```